# Find/Remove in @DBref list items in MongoDB for Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mongodb-query

What would be the best approach to find and update nested list items as `@DBRef` in MongoDB for Spring?

I have a **AppliedApplication** class:

```
@Document(collection = "applied_application")
public class AppliedApplication {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("program")
    @DBRef
    private List<Program> programList;

    // getters and setters

}
```

With a **Program** class as `@DBRef`:

```
@Document(collection = "program")
    public class Program {

        @Id
        private String id;
        @Field("program_name")
        private String programName;

        // getters and setters

    }
```

I'm looking for a way to find and update the nested list items using the following queries:

Query used for finding a **Program** object by It's **Id** from **AppliedApplication** collection:

```
Query query = new Query();
     query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(applicationId)
      .and("program.$id").is(new ObjectId(programId)));

Program program = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Program.class);
```

Query used for removing list item from **AppliedApplication**:

```
Update update = new Update().pull("program", new BasicDBObject("program.$id", new ObjectId(programId)));

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, AppliedApplication.class);
```

None of them are working and I'm completely clueless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Find:**

Use `positional operator`/`$elemMatch` for finding the matching Program DBRef in the AppliedApplication.

Using [`$positional`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId(applicationId)).and("program.$id").is(new ObjectId(programId)));
query.fields().position("program", 1);
AppliedApplication application = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, AppliedApplication.class);
Program program = application.getProgramList().get(0);
```

Using [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) projection

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId(applicationId)));
query.fields().elemMatch("program", Criteria.where("$id").is(new ObjectId(programId)));
AppliedApplication application = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, AppliedApplication.class);
Program program = application.getProgramList().get(0);
```

**Remove:**

Use `$pull` to remove the DBRef from list of program DBref's.

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("$id").is(new ObjectId(programId)));
Update update = new Update().pull("program", query);
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, AppliedApplication.class);
```

**Add**

Use `$push` to add new programs to the list.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId(applicationId)));
Update update = new Update().push("program", new DBRef("program", new ObjectId(programId));
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, AppliedApplication.class);
```

Comment: How to push back an item inside the list?

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: I have something like this:
Query queryPromotion = Query.query(Criteria.where(ID).is(promotionId));
        List<DBRef> shops = shopIds.stream().map(shopId -> new DBRef("shop", shopId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Update update =  new Update().push("shops").each(shops);
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(queryPromotion, update, PromotionDto.class);

But it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

First Query would run if you return the AppliedApplication

```
Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id")
            .is(new ObjectId(applicationId))
            .and("program.$id")
            .is(new ObjectId(programId)));
AppliedApplication  application = this.mongoOperations.findOne(query, AppliedApplication .class);
```

And then use application object to get the program.

For the second query you need to change ,

```
 Update update = new Update().pull("program", new BasicDBObject("$id", new ObjectId(programId)));

 mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, AppliedApplication.class);
```

Replace --> abc.$id  to $id

Comment: For second query you need to add change Query object as given below,                                          Update update = new Update().pull("program", new BasicDBObject("program.$id", new ObjectId(programId)));

Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id")
        .is(new ObjectId(applicationId))
        .and("program.$id")
        .is(new ObjectId(programId)));
  

mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), update, AppliedApplication.class);

Comment: How to push back an item inside the list?